# How can I avoid my player from jumping through objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my player jumps in front of an object it will just jump right through it and I don't know how to fix it. I know it is because I am using transform to move my player but this has been the easiest way for it to jump so I don't want to change that. Here is my code to move my player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{   
    private Vector3 newPos;
    private Vector3 up = new Vector3 (0, .3f, 0);
    private bool jumping = false;
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Start(){
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void Update(){
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;

        if (!jumping) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
                newPos = Vector3.forward + transform.position;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0);
                transform.position = (newPos);
                transform.position = newPos + up;               
            } 
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
                newPos = Vector3.back + transform.position;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 180, 0);
                transform.position = (newPos);
                transform.position = newPos + up;
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
                newPos = Vector3.right + transform.position;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 90, 0);
                transform.position = (newPos);
                transform.position = newPos + up;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
                newPos = Vector3.left + transform.position;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, -90, 0);
                transform.position = (newPos);
                transform.position = newPos + up;
            }               
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Ground")) 
            jumping = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
            jumping = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need some sort of collision detection

Comment: I guess you could do something like you did for the jumping and set the "speed" into the respective direction to 0. You might need to set the collision detection mode to continuous for this to stop the player directly on hitting so it doesn't glitch a few pixels into the block or increase the collider of the player (to the sides an possibly to the top) or the objects a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are applying a transform on the player position - you really need to calculate a route from the current position to the destination implied by the transformation, and then do collision detection on every intermediate point.

This is a problem with many examples on the web, but googling Unity Collision Detection will suggest a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a GameObject with [`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) attached to it, and you want to detect collision while moving it, you must use the [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) and [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) functions instead of moving its `transform` component directly.

So, code such as `transform.position = newPos + up;` and `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 180, 0);` must changed to `rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos + up);` and `rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0));`.

Enable `Rigidbody` Interpolation to move the GameObject smoothly. Also, `isKinematic` must be true/enabled or else, using `MovePosition` and `MoveRotation` will be useless just like moving `Rigidbody` by `transform.position`...

```
public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 newPos;
    private Vector3 up = new Vector3(0, .3f, 0);
    private bool jumping = false;
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;

        if (!jumping)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                newPos = Vector3.forward + transform.position;
                rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos);
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos + up);
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                newPos = Vector3.back + transform.position;
                rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0));
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos);
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos + up);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                newPos = Vector3.right + transform.position;
                rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos);
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos + up);
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                newPos = Vector3.left + transform.position;
                rigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0));
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos);
                rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos + up);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
            jumping = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
            jumping = true;
    }
}
```